# Indexing related information in Apache Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, solrj

Just wanted to some advice about how to index information (two fields) that are related into SOLR.

Let's say I have two fields like this:

```
"name": ["XF300A01",
           "XF300A23",
           "XF300A22",
           "XF300A03",
           ],
"value": ["0",
           "1",
           "100",
           "3",
           "4",
           "30",
           "163",
           "10"],
```

In this example, we might search for say: `name: XF300A01 and value: 3`

Here we are looking for any documents that have name XF300A01 and also any documents that have value 3. But what we actually want to look for is the name that has a given value. For example, we would want to say search where we have XF300A01 = 3.

At the moment, the data is not stored in this way. I was wondering what the best way to index the information is so it is related. I've read it could be as simple as concating say the name and value like XF300A01_3

I saw this link: https://bryanbende.com/development/2015/01/31/concatenating-fields-with-apache-solr

But I'm storing this information programmatically via Java so I can create any structure or values that need to be stored easily.

I thought something like this could be the way:

```
"name": ["XF300A01",
           "XF300A23",
           "XF300A22",
           "XF300A03",
           ],
"value": ["0",
           "1",
           "100",
           "3",
           "4",
           "30",
           "163",
           "10"],
"name_value": [
           "XF300A01_100",
           "XF300A03_3"],
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your `name_value` suggestion should work fine. Do you have any case where it doesn't?

Comment: @MatsLindh I don't see how it can work if I want to search on a range of numbers for the part which comes after the _ 

Could that be possible somehow? Maybe I want to search for this name XF300A01 and a range of 20-100 for the part coming after _

Comment: In that case you'll need to normalize the number format, for example index it as `XF300A01_0020` and `XF300A01_0100` - i.e. as big of a number range as required. You can then query it as `name_value:[XF300A01_0020 TO XF300A01_0100]`. The sort order of the token will be used for the range search.